# Atom - Opening Multi Folder Project From Different Hierarchies

Tags: atom-editor

the thing is, I want to open folder from "hellobill-retail-service"
and "hellobill-retail-web/view" at one go

is it any command to do it? as long as I know it can only select multiple folders from same hierarchy...

I know I can do it separately, but can it done with one go? I dont want to make my project folder histories dirty because it contains all my important projects

or, alternatively, can we some kind like, bookmark projects (along with all opened files) because file/reopen project is like temporary right?

[Here is my htdocs folders...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBVe.png)

[here is inside my hellobill-retail-web folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fFG7.png)

[selecting multiple folders from same level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik94G.png)

[one of my projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXIBX.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several project packages (e.g. [project-plus](https://atom.io/packages/project-plus) or [project-manager](https://atom.io/packages/project-manager)) that can save and restore your current projects, even when consisting of several folders.

Comment: how to use that? owh they have their own documentation right? thanks! I'll try.